# Proper way to work with lists that are constantly changing in python

Tags: python, multithreading, list, queue, locking

I have a list in python that I am always looking at its first element, do some work with it, then remove that first element.

However, at the same time, new elements can be inserted in this list at the same time. They can also be inserted in the `[0]` position as well like in the below example:

```
import threading
import time

class listener:

    def __init__(self):

        thread = threading.Thread(target=self.run, args=())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()

    def run(self):

        while True:

            if time.monotonic() >= Car.cars_list[0].time:
                # other stuff happens to the 0th element
                # what happens if a new element is insrted just now in car_list?
                Cars.cars_list.pop(0)


class Car:
    # list that is always sorted according to car time parameter
    cars_list = []

    def __init__(self, id, model, time):

        self.id = id

        self.model = model

        self.time = time

        # method that inserts the car to cars_list based on time with simple binary search
        Car.insert(self, Carr.cars_list)

    @staticmethod
    def insert(x, a):
        lo = 0
        hi = len(a)

        while lo < hi:

            mid = (lo + hi) // 2

            if x.time < a[mid].time:

                hi = mid

            else:

                lo = mid + 1

        a.insert(lo, x)
```

What happens if a new car is inserted in the 0th element while the listener is doing some stuff on the current 0th element.

It seems to me that I need to lock cars_list from being changed when I am working on it inside the while True loop including the pop(0) line.

Or maybe use some type of buffer/queue. Any suggestions?

Comment: I think context here might be helpful in addition to the code (a bit of the reverse of the usual SO suggestions). Why are things being inserted into arbitrary positions in the list?

Comment: In other words, normally you could use something like FIFO or FILA but you're suggesting that there is some insertion order and that should probably be explained.

Comment: In _other_ other words, this could well be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @roganjosh yes i commented on the order of the list. I am sorting them in terms of time parameter. 'car.insert' is a method that puts cars in time sorted manner. This is explained in the comments of the code

Comment: @Chris what I want is to be able to do some work on all 'cars' starting form the one that has the smallest time from the time parameters. I think its quite simple. For example, I want all cars to fill_gas() and then drive() and cars instance excepts a parameter called 'time' to which i can then know which car should do all those tasks first.

Comment: @user7331538, in that case, consider using a [priority queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#priority-queue-implementation-notes) instead of a list. Using an appropriate data structure can simplify code, improve performance, improve clarity, and a variety of other things. I'll come back and add a proper answer later when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

If you need (as in your example) to examine the first element and then *perhaps* remove it (and do further processing), you should take a **lock** around the examination and (potential) removal, but you can **release** the lock during the processing (that doesn’t refer to the container).

If you always remove the first element, `list.pop` is already **atomic** in Python.  (Of course, it might throw if the list might be (or become) empty.)

Also note that removing from the *end* of a list is much faster than from the beginning.

Comment: so by locking the examination code  ( after "if time.monotonic()...) you are saying that if somewhere else in the code, cars_list[0]  become a different/new element, that does not effect cars_list[0] being examined in the locked code? im not sure if that is true

Comment: @user7331538: You have to take the lock *before* using `cars_list[0]` in the `if` condition.